# Understanding of an example of "extending scalars"

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, tensor-products

The following is an example in the *Abstract Algebra* by Dummit and Foote:

[image]

[image]

I don't understand in this example why $\iota$ is an isomorphism. By Theorem 8, I can get
$$
id_N=\Phi\circ\iota
$$
which implies that $\iota$ is [injective](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Injection_iff_Left_Inverse) and $\Phi$ is surjective. Why is $\iota$ surjective or $\Phi$ is injective?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, my previous answer was incorrect: I attempted to be too fancy.

It looks like a straightforward approach is probably best. Take a simple tensor in $R \otimes_R N$ which will be of the form $r \otimes n = r(1 \otimes n) = r \iota (n)$. Arbitrary elements are finite sums of simple tensors so since $\iota$ is a homomorphism, we are done.

Comment: Thanks you for your answer. I don't quite follow your argument. How do you show that $\iota$ is surjective? (Or you are using a different approach?)

Comment: The definition of surjective is that every element in the codomain has a corresponding element in the domain.

Comment: Ah, $\iota(\sum rn)=\sum r\otimes n$ for a finite sum.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\varphi: R \times N \to N$, $(r,n) \mapsto rn$ be the $R$-bilinear multiplication map, and let $\Phi: R \otimes_R N \to N$ be the map induced by the [universal property of the tensor product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product#Universal_property), so $rn = \varphi(r,n) = \Phi(r \otimes n)$.  We show that the map
\begin{align*}
\iota: N &\to R \otimes_R N\\
n &\mapsto 1 \otimes n
\end{align*}
and $\Phi$ are inverse, hence are isomorphisms.  Note that
$$
\Phi(\iota(n)) = \Phi(1 \otimes n) = \varphi(1,n) = 1 \cdot n = n
$$
and since $\Phi$ and $\iota$ are $R$-linear, then
\begin{align*}
\iota\left(\Phi\left(\sum_\alpha r_\alpha \otimes n_\alpha \right)\right) &= \iota\left(\sum_\alpha \Phi(r_\alpha \otimes n_\alpha)\right) = \iota\left(\sum_\alpha r_\alpha n_\alpha \right) = \sum_\alpha \iota(r_\alpha n_\alpha)\\
&= \sum_\alpha 1 \otimes r_\alpha n_\alpha = \sum_\alpha r_\alpha \otimes n_\alpha \, .
\end{align*}
(Every tensor is a finite sum of simple tensors, so here the sum is over $\alpha$ in some finite index set $I$.)  Thus $\Phi$ and $\iota$ are (mutually inverse) isomorphisms.